# How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I can't work out how to autoplay a video using the [new embed code style for Youtube](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+YoutubeApiBlog+%28YouTube+API+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Reader). I tried adding &autoplay=1 to the url, which worked with the old style, but it didn't work. For example, http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY is the embed link, but http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY&autoplay=1 doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: This is outdated. 'mute=1' is required now. See:
[Answering StackOverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230411/youtube-embedded-video-autoplay)

Comment: Yes, I needed to add ?autoplay=1&mute=1 for autoplay to work in chrome. Thanks

Comment: So just to be clear, chrome will only allow autoplay if the video is muted? There is no way to force autoplay with the sound on?

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Just put `?autoplay=1` in the url the video will autoload.

So your url would be: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1`.

In case you wanna disable autoplay, just change from `1` to `0`:
`?autoplay=0`.

If you embed the Youtube video in an iframe, you need to add `allow="autoplay"` to the HTML. Example: `<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as of right now. It worked perfectly 1 week ago.

Comment: Hmm, looks like this might be an extension on my Chrome that updated in the last week. Ignore that comment. :)

Comment: The first parameter after the video ID needs to start with "?" ,all parameters AFTER that needs to be added with "&". If you had for example "?rel=0&autoplay=1" it would be the same as "?autoplay=1&rel=0" and they would both work.

Comment: This answer still works 2016. Just adding the info, since it's the first result that pops up on google.

Comment: Some additional explanation since this is so high in the goog results. The part of the URL following '?' is the Query String and what you need is the 'autoplay' key with value '1'. So for example, '.../embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1?rel=1' would also be wrong because then you would have 'autoplay' with value '1?rel=1'. The Query String begins with '?' and is separated into key=value pairs by the '&' symbol. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure

Comment: **Update for 2017:** Now in iframe need add one more conf:  allow="autoplay" acording to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes so your iframe will loks like: 
`<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>`

Comment: it's an ordinary answer as I found in the youtube developer forum. but we must include cc_load_policy

Comment: don't work since a youtube update end 2020

Comment: it doesn't work with only `autoplay`, but it works with `mute` - &mute=1

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 37):

Chrome blocks audio content being played without any user interaction.

So, a work-around is to start the video muted by adding

`&mute=1`

This will work 100% of the time.

Comment: It works on Chrome for Desktop. It doesn't work on Chrome for Mobile nor Firefox both Desktop and Mobile.

Comment: "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 32):

Actually, you will have to use the "?" instead of "&" for your first parameter only. If you use more than one parameter, you will then have to add "&" to the chain.

For instance, if you want to add autoplay and closed captioning, you will have to add this portion to your embedded video URL: **?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1**.

It would look like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `closed captioning`?

Answer (score 20):

You need to add an extra parameter, alongside the autoplay=1

allow="autoplay"

making it:

```
<iframe src="your-video-url?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is recommended solution for 2020

Answer (score 6):

Okay this is an example for the new embed code for youtube videos.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8v_4O44sfjM" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

if you want to autoplay it, at the `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8v_4O44sfjM"` add the `?autoplay=1` parameter

So the code will look like this:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8v_4O44sfjM?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

i tried this on my blog and it works ! Hope this help (:

Answer (score 6):

The only way I was able to get autoplay to work was to use the iframe player api.

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<script>
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '480',
        width: '853',
        videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'controls': 0
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: still not playing

Answer (score 5):

[YouTube Help](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56107) says that `&autoplay=1` has to be *after the video ID* - I assume, immediately after.

Comment: @Aton: Thanks for your answer. Still doesn't work though. I've updated the question with links.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me in the current youtube embed. Try this, it actually worked for me :)

Hope it helps!

```
<iframe width="925" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iD5zxjySOzw?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a wrong url for youtube auto play `http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY&autoplay=1` this url display youtube id as whole`JW5meKfy3fY&autoplay=1` which youtube rejects to play. we have to pass autoplay variable to youtube, therefore you have to use `?` instead of `&` so your url will be `http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1` and your final iframe will be like that.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xzvScRnF6MU?autoplay=1" width="960" height="447" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You forgot to change the `&` to `?` in the right way to do it. (before the iframe)

Answer (score 3):

Just add **?autoplay=1** after url in embed code, example :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
oHg5SJYRHA0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Change it to:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

YouTube auto play works only desktop in need to work mobile just make changes in JavaScript. Like

```
<div id="player"></div>
                    var tag = document.createElement('script');
                    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
                    var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: 'VideoID',
      playerVars: {   
            'autoplay': 1,   
            'rel': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'playsinline': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'controls': 0,
            'color':'white',
            'loop': 1,
            'mute':1,
            // 'origin': 'https://meeranblog24x7.blogspot.com/'
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        // 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.playVideo();
    player.mute();
  }var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

See More :- [YouTube auto play for 5 seconds](https://meeranblog24x7.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-add-youtube-video-with-auto-play.html)

Comment: This is the solution that worked best for me. I would take it a step further and add a wrapper div `<div class="video-container"><div id="player"></div></div>` and add the responsive css to make the iframe responsive: `.video-container {overflow: hidden;position: relative;width:100%;} .video-container::after {padding-top: 56.25%;display: block;content: '';} .video-container iframe {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 3):

It's not working since April of 2018 because Google decided to give greater control of playback to users. You just need to add autoplay=1&mute=1 to your URL. Autoplay Policy Changes

```
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-SFcIUEvNOQ autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"
style="border: solid 4px #37474F"></iframe>
```

You can get more detail from the already submitted answer
[YouTube Autoplay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685142/youtube-autoplay-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

None of yours are solved my problem. But, I found a good solution for me to work properly right now. In between  tags write this code:

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/**[CHANGE HERE WITH YOUR YOUTUBE VIDEO ID]**?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect one which works for me is adding a mute=1 paramater.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1&mute=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Comment: I do not see much difference between you answer and [this answer from 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556981/3157428). Please answer only in case the answer is not present already.