# Autoplay youtube videos in android

Tags: html, android, youtube, autoplay

I am trying to autoplay youtube videos on android, the same thing as in

[How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube)

The following HTML works in google chrome browser, but not in the browser in android emulator.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?autoplay=1&vq=medium" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Can anyone shed light on this ?

Comment: Any luck on this... 2 years later?

Comment: +1 to this post. No solution is found yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16572204/259465), disabling autoplay is slowly becoming a standard in mobile browsers. This is happening to prevent unwanted sound from playing and to conserve battery.

You may want to give the method from [this article](http://www.centurion-project.org/articles/how-to-autoplay-html5-video-on-android) a shot.

```
function callback () {
    document.querySelector('video').play();
}

window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);

<video poster preload="true">
    <source src="video.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This does not work because JavaScript does not have acces to the code inside the iframe. I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note replace videoLink with the embed URL from YouTube.

```
src=//videoLink?autoplay=1
```