# Phonegap error on Android GetPTLAFormat

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing an app using jQuery mobile and phone gap. Everything seems to be working fine but when running the app on a connected Android phone we see tons of errors like this in the Eclipse logcat

```
:0: GetPTLAFormat: invalid format
```

Any idea what this is or how to resolve it?

Comment: This seems to be a recent issue - we've just hit the same thing but only on a specific device - an 'International S4'. Could you let us know what you are doing, and what device you are running on.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it has something to do with a new standard for disabling auto events. There is a similar question about [Embedding iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416935/youtube-iframe-embeds-cannot-autoplay-on-android) where they are having an issue with auto-playing videos.

I have had the same issue with a jquerymobile cordova app. My index page is a splash page and when cordova has successfully loaded it navigates to my main application page. I was using `jQuery.mobile.navigate(myPage);`. This gave me about 20 `:0: GetPTLAFormat: invalid format` errors. I tried `jQuery.mobile.changePage` instead and got only 3 errors.

As the page transition happens without any input from the user I tried giving my splash screen image an `onclick` even to transition instead. Not very practical for the final application, but just as a test. I still get the errors with `navigate`, however with an onclick and `changePage` I do not get any errors.

My conclusion is that the new standard doesn't allow automatic playing and transitioning etc. I still haven't figured out a way to get around this but the solution seems to be to have a user trigger the event and it solves the problem.

Comment: I forgot to ask, what phone are you using and what operating system? I did not have these errors on the Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2 however I get them when using an S4 running 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

To **hide it from Eclipse logcat**, enter the following as a **filter**/search term in logcat:

```
^(?!.*(GetPTLAFormat)).*$
```