# Error on Samsung S4 "GetPTLAFormat: Invalid format"

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am having a hybrid android application (Android web view + JS/HTML UI).
Few day back application was working perfectly on all the devices but from last few days application is not working on Samsung S4 device Android 4.2.2.

In logs i am getting following erros while starting the app:
`E/IMGSRV(22014): 0: GetPTLAFormat: Invalid format`

How can i fix this issue? from the posts given on this site it looks like issue with auto play or auto navigation. How to work around this issue.

Comment: Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036238/phonegap-error-on-android-getptlaformat

Comment: I would agree with Swannil that this looks like a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036238/phonegap-error-on-android-getptlaformat, the answer there looks good.

Answer (score -2):

To **hide it from Eclipse logcat**, enter the following as a **filter**/search term in logcat:

```
^(?!.*(GetPTLAFormat)).*$
```

Comment: Why the minus? This was the best solution I found so far :D

Comment: This just hides the error and doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: Gentlemen, there is no fix for this bug. The only way to make Eclipse logcat more managable is to hide the error. This comment wasn't meant as a fix, it was just meant to assist you in debugging to not have it spam the error repeatedly. Please don't down vote. Trying to help.