# Autoplay an embedded youtube video

Tags: youtube, adobe, autoplay

Working with Adobe DPS to create an app. Trying to embed a Youtube video with Folio Overlays/Web content and it works perfectly. But is there some way to make it autoplay?

I've tried adding `?autoplay=1` , `&autoplay=1` and `?rel=0&autoplay=1` after the video's ID but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Ciao,
Elin

Answer (score 0):

How can you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416935/youtube-iframe-embeds-cannot-autoplay-on-android/16572204#16572204), some mobile plataforms are disabling autoplay on web content, on android you can use the youtube api as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354621/youtube-api-android-autostart).

[YouTube API Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)