# Auto click youtube play button on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to auto click the youtube play button on page load in mobile device. I am using the iframe to show youtube video . Its auto play on desktop but showing play button on mobile device .
I am using this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.ytp-large-play-button').click();
});
</script>
```

but not working for me . Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use `?autoplay=1` in the embed instead?

Comment: i want autoplay on mobile device also

Comment: i used there but only work on desktop

Comment: Have you embedded the youtube player?

Comment: where are you testing ?  I mean andriod ? IOS ?

Comment: android device and yes i embeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Iframe embed auto play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play)

Answer (score 2):

If You are using jquery make sure you have a Jquery file or You can use CDN check below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use this one when your page is loaded the button is trigger.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ytp-large-play-button').trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: can you give me an error in console log ? I'm pretty sure this codes is work fine. maybe you have some error issues..

Comment: but on load button not click auto

Comment: Do you have a Jquery file ?

Comment: Can you send some of Your codes ? maybe I'll check Your codes.

Comment: <iframe width="1349" height="759" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pQJ6xghaaGs?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     
    $('.ytp-large-play-button').trigger('click');
   
 });
</script>

Comment: your codes is not correct places.. put the trigger function inside playVideo function.

Answer (score 2):

you can use iframe onload event like this

```
<iframe src="http://..." onload='playVideo();'>
<script type="text/javascript">
function playVideo(){
   $('.ytp-large-play-button').click();
}
</script>
```

Try this this function call when iframe is load

Answer (score 2):

Videos can autoplay on desktop but why can you not get them to autoplay on mobile websites when the page loads? The answer is that the different OS developers intentionally disabled autoplay on mobile devices in order to protect user’s bandwidth. Many data providers charge based on the amount of data consumed, so the OS developers decided it was in the best interest of the user to not have a video automatically begin playing when the page loaded so it would not start racking up data charges. Instead mobile web videos require the user to click them to start.

[check more](https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/)

I am not sure if you can trigger event inside iFrame...

Why doesn't video Autoplay on Mobile device https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

For your case try this

A solution I've just been working on for autoplaying would be to instantiate the player with an empty video on page load:

```
var player = new YT.Player('yt-media-player', {
  height: height,
  width: width,
  videoId: ''
});
```

Then on the click event of opening the lightbox you can load the particular video and call it to play:

```
player.loadVideoById(youtubeId);

player.playVideo();
```

[Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602725/cant-autoplay-youtube-video-in-android-chrome)

Comment: @AvinashGupta, Can you trigger code inside iFRAME? that is my question. I don't think so

Comment: check this https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

Comment: <iframe width="1349" height="759" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pQJ6xghaaGs?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Plz check the link https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

Comment: i will check that link