# Replace img with iframe on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

Im pretty new to js/jquery and need some help from someone more knowledgeable!

I have had a good look on this site and on the web but cannot find the answer myself. I've played around myself but with my limited knowledge I just cannot figure out what to do next.

**What I've got**

I have an `img` that when clicked is replaced by an `iframe` (youtube video), much like a placeholder/poster, and that works perfectly with the below code, which I originally found here: [How to add a splash screen/placeholder image for a YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725683/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-placeholder-image-for-a-youtube-video):

```
<div class="playbutton"></div>    
<img src="image.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/videolink">
        <script>
                $('img').click(function(){
            var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>';
            $(this).replaceWith(video);
        });
        </script>
```

As I said - it works perfectly when the image is clicked it *is* replaced by the video.

**The Problem**

I have now added a play button (currently a `div` but I can use `img` instead) floating above the `img`. If I click on the play button nothing happens (obviously as it is nothing to do with the script).

I want this play button to "trigger" the replacing of the `img` with the `iframe` but I do not have a clue what to add to my script to make this happen.

**What I'm looking for**

I'm looking for the play button to be the "trigger" when clicked or ideally to have **both** the play button and the `img` as "triggers" so it works if a user clicks on the image too and not just the play button.

**While I've got you...**

Would I also be able to replace the `iframe` with the `img` again if a close button is added to the mix and clicked on?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Dale

Comment: Hi Dale , can you make an example on jsfiddle? it makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: I havent used jsfiddle before now so i hope its all in there correct: http://jsfiddle.net/ANRHT/2/

Comment: Yea, except for js which you gotta put in js section , I've made a correct one including the solution to your problem, check the answer ;)

Comment: You can use [Codegena iframe generator tool](http://codegena.com/iframe-generator/) to generate iframes that load on image click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do All you want including close button:
Here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ANRHT/6/

js:

```
 $('.playbutton,img').click(function(){
   var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+$('img').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>';
   $('.video').hide();
   $('.tube').html(video);
   $('.close').show();
 });
 $('.close').click(function(){
   $('.video').show();
   $('.tube').empty();
   $('.close').hide();
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="video">
  <div class="playbutton">Play</div>    
  <img src="http://cdn0.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/5372321/battlefield3-screen-12.0_cinema_640.0.jpeg" data-video="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U8HVQXkeU8U?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&showinfo=0&autohide=3&modestbranding=1">
</div>
<div class="tube"></div>
<div class="close">Close X</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that - i did warn you i hadnt used jsfiddle before :) I have played around a bit with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ANRHT/7/ to add in some images and thats working perfect on jsfiddle but i have added everything into my site and the iframe on click is loading the 404 page rather than the video from data-video...i will keep playing

Comment: Glad it helped, js fiddle makes it easier for you to explain your problem and for others to work on it, So you'll get your problem solved much faster, any way, please accept the answer if you think it covers your question completely.

Comment: @Dale1985 Nice , I can have a look on your site to find the problem if you want.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, can i just clarify if the js should be added in the header or someone else? im just trying to figure why the iframe is showing the 404 page rather than the video. it works perfectly in jsfiddle so it's the markup somewhere on my site.

Comment: @Dale1985 Yes, you can put the js in <script></script> tag in header, but i'd personally load it from an external js file, if you get the img replaced by iframe that means the js is working, try to find the location of iframe and see if it's not what you set in data-video, Post a link here and I'll tell you where the problem is.

Comment: all is now solved - I had to change var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+ $('**img**').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>'; to var video = '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="'+ $('**.vid**').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe></div>'; Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me out. Modified it for my needs and BAM!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#play-button").on('click', function () {
    //this fires the same click event from your code.
    $("img").trigger('click');
});
$("#close-button").on('click', function () {
    $("iframe").replaceWith("<img src='image.jpg'>");
});
```

Comment: @AndersLindén that won't make any difference.  In fact the `>` is not even needed.

Comment: Isn´t that a practice that jQuery assumes?

Comment: @AndersLindén what do you mean?

Comment: That the preferred way of creating new elements with jQuery is to always close them?

Comment: @AndersLindén probably, but `>` is as closed as `/>`, for `<img>` anyway

Comment: thank you, i did think it was something simple i needed to add but i didnt know what...