# how to hide a video before playing?

Tags: wordpress, video

I am using the following to put a video on a wordpress site:

```
<param name="src" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="560" width="950">

<embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov" height="560" width="950" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
```

The part I don't like about this is that you can see the opening frame of the video whenever you are on the page. I would like it if there was a way to make it show just black or show a blank screen until you click the play button.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a video placeholder as described in this thread on Stack Overflow: [How to add a splash screen/placeholder image for a YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725683/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-placeholder-image-for-a-youtube-video)

One point of consideration: If jQuery/JavaScript fails, the video won't load either.

**Update**

In your HTML:

```
<img class="video-placeholder" src="placeholder.jpg" data-video="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov">
```

In your JS file:

```
$('.video-placeholder').click(function(){
    var video = '<param name="src" value="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="560" width="950">
    <embed src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '" height="560" width="950" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

Comment: Where within this code would I put the cover image?

$('img').click(function(){
    var video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
});

<img src="cover.jpg" width="950" height="600" />

<param name="src" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="560" width="950">

<embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov" height="560" width="950" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">

Comment: You wouldn't. That cover image goes in the HTML, not the script. Will update my response with more detail.

Comment: So I don't need any of this code that I had before?:            <param name="src" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="560" width="950">

<embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov" height="560" width="950" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">

Comment: It's only this in the html?     <img class="video-placeholder" src="placeholder.jpg" data-video="http://www.mywebsite.com/announcement.mov">

Comment: Another issue is that I can see the javascript code on the webpage when I try this (as if it is text that I wrote in). I thought I could just put javascript code when I was in the text view in wordpress.

Comment: is there somewhere else I am supposed to put javascript code in wordpress?

Comment: Andy, here's what's happening with the code above: You put only the image markup (replace the `data-video` bit with the appropriate URL) in your text editor. When someone clicks on the image, jQuery pulls the `data-video` value into the markup, and replaces the image with new HTML.

Comment: JavaScript should not be placed in the text editor. Add it to an external JS file, or at least in the `footer.php` file between `<script>YOUR SCRIPTS HERE</script>` tags.