# HTML - image cover on object

Tags: html, object, youtube, embed

I'm a begginer, and I need your help :)
I have a simple landing page, made from one long jpg + image mapping.
I've embedded a youtube video in a specific location on the image as an **object** command but I want to show a different image until it is pressed (an image with a play button, for example).

The page will be shown on a facebook tab as well.

Can any1 help me?

P.S - Sorry if I have grammar mistakes :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Using JavaScript:** You could add a Listener to the image so once it is pressed it loads a video.

```
var image = new Image(); //Image with playbutton


//Then load your Video in the EventListener
image.onclick("load", function() {
                    alert("loaded");
```

The function() method will contain the code to run your video

This is a good link about EventListeners http://idratherbewriting.com/javascript/events-and-listeners-javascript/

Comment: Thank you, my question wasn't accurate enough so I posted it again with my code and specifications.

I appreciate your effort and thank you for your help!

the new question is here: http://goo.gl/fXwiWw

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure a placeholder can be implemented via the Youtube API or you could take a look at this, [How to add a splash screen/placeholder image for a YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725683/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-placeholder-image-for-a-youtube-video)

Comment: Thank you, my question wasn't accurate enough so I posted it again with my code and specifications. I appreciate your effort and thank you for your help! the new question is here: goo.gl/fXwiWw