# Timing of creating vs. selecting elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725683/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-placeholder-image-for-a-youtube-video) to create custom thumbnails for embedded YouTube/Vimeo videos.

It is simple - image as placeholder, replace with embed when clicked.

My content is being generated through JSON `$.getJSON` and the click-binding appears not to catch. If I go through the console after the page has loaded and run my binding function, it works fine. So I think my problem is timing - I think that the click-binding is running before the content is generated.

I've tried `$( document ).ready()` and I've tried using a callback (as seen below)

```
    function binding()
    {
    $('.portfolioVideoPlaceholder').click(function(){
                                var video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
                                $(this).replaceWith(video);
                                }
                        );      
    }
    function fillSection(callback)
    {

        $.getJSON('js/Mammola-portfilio-list.json', function (data){.......}
    callback(); 
    }

    fillSection(binding);
```

And my HTML for the placeholders looks like this:
    `<img class="portfolioVideoPlaceholder" src="images/thumb-gpwit.png" data-video="//www.youtube.com/embed/WiOZdLFrbDE">`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where are you calling `binding()`? you haven't included enough code in your question to replicate the problem

Comment: thanks i just added that in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to register a *delegated event handler*, once,  at DOM ready, than to try and reconnect element-based handlers when items are added to the DOM. The handler should be attached to the nearest non-changing ancestor of the dynamic elements. `document` is your default if nothing else is closer/convenient.

e.g. use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.portfolioVideoPlaceholder', function(){} );
```

or preferably

```
$('#someAncestor').on('click', '.portfolioVideoPlaceholder', function(){} );
```

This works by listening for the event to bubble up the DOM to the connected element, *then* it applies the jQuery selector (against the elements in the bubble-chain only), *then* it calls the function for any matching elements *that caused the event*. This is very efficient and means the matching elements only need to exist at event time and not event registration time.

Note: If you are going to use delegated events with a root element, do not use `body`. Instead use `document` as the default. Not many people seem to know this, but if your page styling results in a calculated body height of 0, e.g. thanks to absolute elements, then mouse events *will not* bubble to `body`. They will however always bubble to `document`. Also `$(document)` is faster to parse than `$('body')` (trivial difference mind you).

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation and the additional tidbit!

Comment: What exactly is the difference between _delegated event handler_ and _element-based handler_? I suppose _element-based_ is the way that i was trying to do it initially (a one-time application) vs _delegated event_ which listens for changes in the DOM?

Comment: @Matthew J Mammola: Yes. A delegated handler "delegates" the responsibility for event handling to an ancestor (hence the name). A element-based handler is connected directly to the elements (multiple handlers pointing at the same function).

Comment: Good advice on the "body".

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling binding inside your response function from getJSON? If not, you should.

Alternatively, switch to using "on".

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('body').on('.portfolioVideoPlaceholder', 'click', function(){} );
```

You can call this on your document load, and if it notices a new element, it will bind that function to it and never have to call it again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I switched the order to $('body').on('click', '.portfolioVideoPlaceholder',  function(){} );
It now is functioning as expected, thanks so much!