# Autoplay with <iframe> You Tube video - ?autoplay=1 not working

Tags: html, youtube, autoplay

[How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube)

My code followed these instructions and does not work. I also looked on the YouTube help and they say the same thing -- does not work for me.

```
<html><body>
<iframe width="640" height="385" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0319ZgKMLzw?autoplay" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body>
</html>
```

See it not autoplaying [here](http://amphibiographer.tv/), the code is there in firebug.

Comment: Check las comment of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433300/7818938

Answer (score 3):

Edit your embed code to "?autoplay=1" and add "http://". Here is the working code for you...

```
<iframe width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0319ZgKMLzw?autoplay=1"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add =1 after "autoplay" on your code

Answer (score -1):

try this. It worked for me.

```
private class AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // mimic onClick() event on the center of the WebView
        long delta = 100;
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        float x = view.getLeft() + (view.getWidth()/2);
        float y = view.getTop() + (view.getHeight()/2);

        MotionEvent tapDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
        tapDownEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);
        MotionEvent tapUpEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta + 2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
        tapUpEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);

        view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapDownEvent);
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapUpEvent);
    }
}
```

Somewhere,

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient());
```