# iFrame & Autoplay for youtube does't work

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube, autoplay

[How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube)

Months ago my iFrame code including autoplay have worked with my embedded youtube video, but now It won't autoplay my video. I've tried all iFrame possibilities..

Here is my current code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0319ZgKMLzw?autoplay=1"> </iframe>
```

I'm using wordpress without any plugins.

Comment: You can just paste the URL of your video directly into the WP content editor and it will use oembed to automatically embed and give you autoplay + size options

Comment: thank you very much... never seen that this offers wp...