# Is there any way to get a youtube video to play when my meteor app loads, and know when the video stops so I can play the next one?

Tags: api, meteor, youtube

I am building a joke meteor web app where you hit a button to randomly choose from a collection of youtube videos (to which the user can add). I am making this just to learn about meteor and practice.

I want the first random video to play when the page loads, and for the next random video from the collection to play once the first one has finished.

As of now, a video loads but does not play when the page loads. If you press the button after the initial video loads, it chooses a random video from a collection of videos. You can keep hitting the button forever and it will keep choosing randomly. How can I get the videos to play automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question answers this:
[How can I autoplay a video using the new embed code style for Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube)

But in short it looks like adding "?autoplay=1" to the end of the youtube url should do it.