# Start & Stop a iframe with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I want to make 4 channel in my website, but I want to make start for the first channel automatically and after 5 second start the second channel ... etc

code of channel

The Code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 
var interval = setInterval(function() {
iframes[++n].src = urls[n - 1];
iframe[n].style.display = "block";
console.log(n);
if (n === iframes.length -1)
{
 clearInterval(interval); console.log("all iframes loaded") 
 }
 },
5000)
})
```

```css
.channel1, .channel2, .channel3{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  </head>
<body>
  
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="channel1" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="channel2" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="channel3" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

This code doesn't work, I can listen the commutator talk but I cant see the channel why ?

Comment: Do you mean change the `src` of `iframe` every five seconds?

Comment: @guest271314 No, I have 4 iframe I want, to start to first iframe automatically and after 5 seconds the second channel start .... etc

Comment: Yes, can set initial `iframe` 2-4 `src` to `""` at `html`, at five second increments set each `iframe` 2-4 `src` to url

Comment: How I can make that ? can you give a website Explain that or the code ?

Comment: You can use `setInterval`, see post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `iframe` elements 1-4 `src` to empty string, utilize `setInterval` to set `src` of each `iframe` 1-4 to a url within an array every five seconds until all `iframe` elements have `src` set.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

var urls = ["data:text/plain,b", "data:text/plain,c", "data:text/plain,d"];

var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");

var n = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
  iframes[++n].src = urls[n - 1];
  console.log(n);
  if (n === iframes.length -1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("all iframes loaded")
  }
  
}, 5000)

})
```

```html
<iframe src="data:text/plain,a"></iframe>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I make this but the channel not start ? :'(

Comment: And thaht affiched but after seconds the channel hide and show b, c, d ? Where i make the src of the channel ?

Comment: @Saad _"Where i make the src of the channel ?"_ You can place the url that should be set at each `iframe` in an array; see `urls` at stacksnippets.

Comment: I make our urls in src iframe, all things as right for this moment but after some seconds the channel are hide and showing b,c,d in the page ? why ?

Comment: @Saad Not following. The items within `urls` at stacksnippets are for example to demonstrate process; they can be replaced with the actual urls of the items that you want to set as `src` at `iframe` elements

Comment: Do you have a gmail to send you the code, the see where's the problem ?

Comment: @Saad _"Do you have a gmail to send you the code"_ You can post the full code at Question. Though note, actual original Question appears to be _"I want to make 4 channel in my website, but I want to make start for the first channel automatically and after 5 second start the second channel ... etc"_

Comment: @Saad Set `src` of `iframe` elements 1-3 at `html` to empty string `""`. Replace contents of `urls` array with urls that should be loaded at `iframe` elements 1-3 . At edited Question all `iframe` elements currently have identical `src`

Comment: That's good but I have a small problem the first channel doesn't start automatically and The second problem is all the channel are showed, and after that are refresh. I want to see just the first channel and after 5 second I see the second ... etc

Comment: @Saad You can set `iframe` elements `style` to `display:none`, the set to `display:block` within `setInterval` after setting `src`

Comment: I found the solution about start automatically but I want the solution of second problem :'(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube for autoplay; see previous comment set `style=display:none` at `html`, within `setInterval` after setting `src` ; e.g., `iframe[n].style.display = "block"` before `console.log(n)` at stacksnippets

Comment: I make it display none, but how I make them block after 5 seconds ? this's my question

Comment: @Saad _"I make it display none, but how I make them block after 5 seconds ? this's my question"_ `var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
  iframes[++n].src = urls[n - 1];iframe[n].style.display = "block";
  console.log(n);
  if (n === iframes.length -1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("all iframes loaded")
  }
  
}, 5000)`

Comment: I edited my post can you see where's the error ? all things work but, I can't see the other channel but I can listen the commutator talk

Comment: You are not setting `src` to empty string `""` within `html` or storing urls to set to `src` within an array. At `html` `<iframe class="channel1" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`, at `js` `var urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1",..]`

Comment: I don't know why, but I always have problems with javascript :'(, I create an array with javascript ? and make the src code into them ?

Comment: Like this ? var iframes = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1"
];

Comment: Use pattern at stacksnippets. The only adjustment needed is what you ahve already done, that is to set `display:none` for `iframe` 1-3

Comment: @Saad _"Like this ?"_ Yes, though adjust varibale identifier to `urls`; `iframes` is already defined as `iframe` elements . And also set `<iframe src="">` at `html`. Again, use pattern at stacksnippets, set `style.display = "block"` after setting `src` within `setInterval`

Comment: This ? 

var iframes = [
    '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1">',
    '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1">',
    '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1">'
];

Comment: @Saad No. You had it correct at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533012/start-stop-a-iframe-with-php/36533247?noredirect=1#comment60671330_36533247 except for variable name `var urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BqPmcSGgs3U?autoplay=1", ..]`

Comment: Sorry but I'm beginner in English language, All thing is right in my code, but I have a small problem.
The problem is :
when I click into my file and see them in Mozila, I see just the first channel but after 5 second, I listen the commutator for the second channel but i can't see them why ?

Comment: @Saad No worries. Use same `js` at stacksnippets. Substitute urls to videos for `data:..` at `urls` variable

Comment: Can you edited you comment and give the right code :'( with CSS .. etc, I make all codes without any news :'(