# Wordpress Iframe Autoplay video wont work

Tags: html, css

I cannot proceed the code cause my code wont work
please advise on this code

```
<div id="video-section-pop">
 <button id="close">X</button><br>
 <video controls autoplay>
    <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4J-VkbOwulM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </video>   
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Comment: A ‘<video>’ needs a source, not an iFrame...

Comment: so what if  I will remove the video only the iframe alone

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: my code is the same with the google youve sent

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

More browser changes their Autoplay Policy, such as Google:

Chrome's [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) had change in April of 2018

> Muted autoplay is always allowed. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
> - Muted autoplay is always allowed.
>
>   - Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.

---

**Solution**

You don't need to add youtube's Iframe to the video tag, you just need to add two query strings to youtube's URL

- autoplay=1
- mute=1

it's also working on another modern browser

```
<iframe ... src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4J-VkbOwulM?autoplay=1&mute=1"></iframe>
```

you can check complete code on https://jsfiddle.net/tf3gpb1r/5/

---

**More Reference**

- [youtube-autoplay-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685142/youtube-autoplay-not-working)
- [To Play, or Not to Play – New AutoPlay Policies for Safari 11 and Chrome 64](https://bitmovin.com/play-not-play-new-autoplay-policies-safari-11-chrome-64/)

Comment: Thanks for all the response you've made.