# Youtube video not getting played on html website

Tags: html

I have uploaded three videos on my youtube channel, however, when I'm trying to put those three videos on my HTML website, among those videos one gets played, and the other two videos show the thumbnail but when I try to play it shows that the video is **unavailable**. I've attached the embedded code for that video.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="228" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5jhsfVzcAk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It would be great if someone can suggest something on this!

Comment: I have also same problem,youtube video not working on bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

This video is blocked in embeded mode. Try with this Casey Neistat video id :  **bzE-IMaegzQ** it will work.

Here's the Google's policy : https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en

Comment: where can i use the Casey Neisat video id??

Comment: In ```<iframe width="100%" height="228" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5jhsfVzcAk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>``` there is an ```src``` attribute that contains a youtube link. At the end of the link, here's your video ID

Comment: so as per you, i should replace my video id with the video id you have provided. The video id which you have provided me is playing some other video

Comment: No, I'm telling you the following : your video cannot be embeded on websites. You have to use another one

Comment: I have another video from my youtube channel which has been uploaded normally on my website. any alternate solution could you suggest for this.

Comment: Get it's youtube ID and replace the old one with the new one

Comment: https://youtu.be/oREsN64Hn54 see this is the video which has been successfully uploaded on my website. please suggest something from this now.

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="228" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oREsN64Hn54" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

The autoplay policy was changed recently. 
here is a post describing the options:

[YouTube Autoplay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685142/youtube-autoplay-not-working)

Comment: yes, I know but one video which I had uploaded on youtube is working properly on the website, however, the other two are not working and the one's link I have shared in the question itself.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oREsN64Hn54&t=54s      This is the new video which has been uploaded successfully on my website. Please if possible try to provide any solution for this