# How to auto play Youtube Audio without Click Play Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to make web with audio on backgroud using Youtube audio

I found this code

```
<body>
        <div data-video="Iq1OzH9adIc"
                data-autoplay="1"
                data-loop="1"
                id="youtube-audio">
         </div>
</body>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

But audio will play when button clicked

any suggest how to make it auto play ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685142/youtube-autoplay-not-working

Answer (score 0):

In order to autoplay the youtube in HTML, add autoplay=1 and mute=1 in the src parameter.

> FYI. Without mute parameter to 1, the youtube videos will not be
> playing even if autoplay is enabled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```