# How to autoplay youtube component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, youtube, components

I am using Angular 11 with Angular Youtube Component, but i just don't figure it out how to autoplay it on showing the player without playing it manually
Please Can anyone help me?

```
     <youtube-player  
        [videoId]="'wZti8QKBWPo'" 
        [playerVars]="{controls: 0, mute: 1, autoplay: 1}"
        (ready)="onReady($event)"
        [startSeconds]="30"
        [width]="width"
        [height]="height">
    </youtube-player>
```

when i pass the extra configs [playersVars] to player component, the only property works is the controls property, the rest nothing, i tried to bind from the ts file instead of passing object literal in the html file, then the mute property also works along the controls,

Comment: can you add sample code here? It'll be helpful

Comment: Arunkumar Ramasamy have a look please, Thans

Comment: This info should be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272974/3520837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked an example again and it works. The one reason that it doesn't work it's `startSeconds` property. Somehow, when we add this property it stops to autoplay the video. But without it, it works well.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
    <youtube-player
      [playerVars]="playerConfig"
      [width]=640
      [height]=320
      [videoId]="videoId"
      (ready)="onReady($event)"
    ></youtube-player>
  `,
  selector: 'app-video'
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {
  playerConfig = {
    controls: 0,
    mute: 1,
    autoplay: 1
  };
  videoId = 'XqZsoesa55w';
  ngOnInit() {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  }

  onReady(e): void {
    console.log(e, 'its ready')
  }
}
```

Here is a [working example of app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c9tnrg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvideo%2Fvideo.component.ts).