# How to autoplay iframe videos on button click in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using owl carousel slider, the slider should only visible and 
autoplay when we click on a button, currently I need to double click
to play video, which is not expected
HTML (these are more than 2 sliders, I just put 2 here)

```
<div class="owl-carousel video-slider">
   <div class="video-slide">
      <img src="src/media/testimonial-image1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="item-video">
         <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/n1a3VZY0xgM"></a>
      </div>
      <span class="clickIframeBtn"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="video-slide">
      <img src="src/media/testimonial-image1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="item-video">
         <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/n1a3VZY0xgM"></a>
      </div>
      <span class="clickIframeBtn"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I just have to display a video on the image so, I used position absolute to overlap the video on the image, display none the video slide on first

```
.item-video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00000026;
}

.fa-play-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 72px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I am not good in jquery, I just tried to display block the video div once we click on the icon(button)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel.video-slider').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        items: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        video: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000
    });

    $('.clickIframeBtn').on('click', function(ev) {
        $('.owl-video').show();
        // $('.testimonial-iframe')[0].src += '&autoplay=1';
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

once clicked on span video should autoplay,

Advance big thanks :)

Comment: May be Duplicate for 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube