# How Can I Set a Youtube Video to Autoplay Using R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, youtube

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/schochastics/5c5b2d153625c7e2e8bcf3ea7e874c3a) which will accept a Youtube URL and play the video in the RStudio viewer pane, rather than in a popout browser. It does exactly what I need it to do *except* that I would like it to autoplay when the function has run. I've seen a few other examples ( Like [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-embed-videos-in-shiny/38937) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/GS-3Ze3p7-w) ) where folks insert an `allow = autoplay` or something similar in the UI's `fluidPage` command but I haven't gotten it to work for me. I have additionally tried adding `?autoplay=1` to the URL, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405242/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video-using-the-new-embed-code-style-for-youtube?rq=1), which works generally in any browser but seems to be ignored by R. Here's an example to replicate with:

```
videoplay <- function(url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpHQnCaAJv8")
  
{
  library(shiny)
  xy <- c(784,479)
  url <- gsub("watch\\?v=","embed/",url)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    HTML(paste0('<iframe width="',xy[1],'" height="',xy[2], '" src="', url,"?autoplay=1",'" frameborder="0"></iframe>'))
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  }
  
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server,options=c("launch.browser"=FALSE,"port"=1111)),port=1111,viewer = paneViewer())
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this video autoplay when the function is run? Appreciate any help!